# how to set a split screen on android (java )game

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello I am developing a game in java.
The game should have split screen vertically because i want to set one onclicklistener on top
and another on bottom so the user can play against another..
Like ping pong and tho..
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout containing two views.  Set a click listener on each view.

Comment: But how can i set a layout when I have a canvas already?
I am not experienced on the android development and I know how to do layouts and those... But how to set a layout that will take place on the game itself without hurting its screen?(I mean without controlling the view of the game..?)